# Beginner to MySQL workbench, what is the meaning of connection?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I've downloaded the MySQL workbench and the first screen I see is this:

[image]

From what I understand, MySQL server is hosted on my own machine (localhost). To access this database, I use the following code

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/giraffe", "root", "root");
```

All working great and I have successfully connected to my MySQL server. But, one thing I can't get my head around is what is the meaning of a connection inside of the MySQL workbench? What does it mean to my if I create say 5 connections as opposed to just 1 connection?

I tried running the same code with one deliberately not closing the connection, trying to simulate two connections to the database, still everything works fine with 1 connection on MySQL Workbench,

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_connection

Comment: The connection[s] you open in your app have nothing to do with the connection[s] you open via mySQL workbench. The number of connections you open in one doesn't depend on the number of connections you open in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Workbench can access more than one host.

E.g. your computer is one host with one MySQL instance on localhost.

Furthermore e.g. your friend has also a computer with MySQL installed and shares it on the web. Now you can add a new connection with the ip and port of your friends's computer and the credentials he set on the database (username, pw).

Now you have two connections:

- localhost (your computers MySQL instance)
- John Doe (your firends computer over web)

Comment: Just so I fully understand, so the localhost connections refers to the MySQL server living on my laptop and by creating a new connections, I can refer to someone else's MySQL server?

Comment: Correct. Your localhost connection is a connection to your own computer.